# Enable /system write in TWRP - Systemless root

Tags: twrp, moto-x, systemless-root

Moto X Play (XT1562), SuperSU 2.78 (systemless root), [TWRP 3.0.2-r3](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x-play/orig-development/recovery-twrp-2-8-7-0-t3194656)

- When I flashed TWRP, I chose the option of *not writing* to system to enable OS update (and also made a Nandroid just after flashing it as a backup)
- Now, I made some minor changes to system audio files, without dwelling on consequences -  won't be able to update OS ( update expected this quarter) without flashing stock OS

I want to enable `/system` write option in TWRP ( without flashing TWRP again ) so that :

a) Flash backup Nandroid ( of stock OS from the first Nandroid), if I decide to upgrade OS

b) If I don't want to upgrade, have a *complete* Nandroid and tweak further knowing that I can safely roll back changes

In other words be able to backup and restore `/system` along with data

**Is it possible and how ( please provide detailed instructions )?**

**Edit:** Flashing different versions didn't help - see my [unanswered post on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x-play/orig-development/recovery-twrp-2-8-7-0-t3194656/page37#post69124377)

Comment: If you wanted to reset TWRP's configuration (and thus be able to access the wizard again), you could simply delete the **.twrps** file under **/sdcard/TWRP/**.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman: Thanks I don't find that file - this is a modded TWRP

Comment: I found a workaround, as you can read in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the issue was TWRP's fault. To make the **/system** partition writeable, one could:

- Uncheck the checkbox near **Mount system partition read-only**, in the **Mount** section of TWRP (screenshot at the end of this answer);
- Delete, move or rename the **.twrps** file to force TWRP's setup wizard to trigger, in order to make **/system** writeable. This file is located under **sdcard/TWRP**, and can be managed directly from TWRP's **File Manager**, accessible from the **Advanced** section of the recovery. Notice that any TWRP setting customization aside of themes will be reverted.

[image: TWRP Mount menu]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46780/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-death-mask-salesman).