# Switch over from systemless root to system (traditional) root

Tags: rooting, systemless-root

Internet search reveals a couple of ways of doing this:

- This [reddit post](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/448c48/how_to_remove_systemless_root_and_replace_it_with/) suggests a couple of methods, which are simple
- In contrast, this [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63816659&postcount=2769) mentions that even flashing `boot.img` is not enough and you need to clean flash system as well - in other words complete ROM

**Do I run a risk if I choose the first method and flash the last version of traditional root?**

Anything else I need to bear in mind ?

**Edit: Any other method ?**

Comment: Rather than answering to your question's body, I answered to the title. Do make me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman: That's fine - that's the crux. Will revert if there is a problem ( some xposed issues I am attributing to systemless root, as a guess - if they are resolved  otherwise, needn't revert)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this very issue some time ago. In my case, [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus5x/comments/4gyelu/traditional_root_not_the_default_systemless_root/) Reddit post helped.

Basically, to migrate to the traditional system root, you need to have the **TWRP** recovery installed, the latest SuperSU flashable ZIP, your phone to be already systemlessly rooted and SuperSU by Chainfire to be your root manager app.

Next, boot to Android, open SuperSU and navigate to the **Settings** tab. Find the **Full Unroot** button and tap it. When SuperSU asks if you're sure to unroot, **accept**. When it asks whether to restore the old **boot.img**, **deny**.

When the phone reboots, input the appropriate keys and boot into TWRP. Once there, make sure that the **/data** partition be mounted. Then, under the **Advanced** menu, start TWRP's **Terminal** and issue the following commands:

```
cd /data
echo SYSTEMLESS=false > .supersu
```

. Alternatively, you can use

```
echo SYSTEMLESS=false > /data/.supersu
```

to achieve the same result. This creates the file **.supersu** inside **/data**.

Finally, flash the SuperSU ZIP to force SuperSU to use the standard, old root procedure.

---

### The .supersu file

This file is checked (e.g. *sourced*) by the SuperSU ZIP. If it finds the entry `SYSTEMLESS` and it has value `false`, the installer will perform a system install. If the value is `true`, the installation will be systemless.

Comment: Thanks .  Was xposed unaffected? Just for curiosity what does the command exactly do ? Asking since for my device ( Moto X Play ) I had to `echo "SYSTEMLESS=true" >> /data/.supersu` to make it work ( IDK of that makes a difference to your solution) +1

Comment: Also, can I flash the last version of system root or any version as good?

Comment: @beeshyams I cannot say if Xposed will work fine - I was on Android 7 when applying this solution, so no Xposed - but if the issue was that Xposed couldn't find **su**, then yes, it'll work again. My two commands and yours do the same thing: they create the file **.supersu** inside **/data**, and write the string `SYSTEMLESS=false` inside it. This file is checked by SuperSU's ZIP, and if that string is set to `false`, then the rooting method will be the traditional one. Lastly, my test was performed with the SuperSU ZIP v2.79-201612051815, so I cannot really say it'll work for an older ZIP.

Comment: I am on 2.79 version , so it should be fine

Comment: It's interesting that you advise not to restore boot image when doing full unroot. I tried your method and because I did not restore it I never got root when installing in system mode not system-less. That's probably also the reason @beeshyams had problems. Also he did put SYSTEMLESS=true (not false) so it seems he was moving from system mode to systemless which is the exact contrary of what this article is about.

Comment: Good day. You're right in saying that beeshyams put `SYSTEMLESS=true`, whilst I was babbling about `SYSTEMLESS=false`. That way, he got himself a systemless root instead of a traditional one. Why he says that it worked, I don't know. About the boot image restoration and a good part of the solution, I merely reported what I found on the link you can see in my answer, as such method worked for me at the time. I'm afraid I can no longer do any troubleshooting about SuperSU, since I'm currently using LineageOS' own root solution.

Comment: @MarcElser and Salesman- deep apologies for my first comment that caused this confusion. To set the record straight 1. In the first comment , I was referring to what I needed to while rooting the phone in system less mode for the first time , as I read up on XDA (your thread?) and was trying to understand to how it works 2. Your solution worked fine for me and I am in traditional root now//

Comment: Couple of other things that may come in handy to other visitors 1. If root is sticky and doesn't vanish , [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63615067) helps, as it did for me. 2. If you simply switch to system root and restore `/data` (which was in system less mode earlier), you are back to systemless mode again ! Ti Bu is the only way out