# Root Issue : Rebooted when app is running

Tags: rooting, device-firmware

I am new to this. I have flashed twrp.img in my phone. Then using twrp recovery , I have installed SuperSU.zip file.

I installed root checker and it shows "device has root permissions". But the problem is , When I am using apps like system app uninstaller (I tried many apps requires root permissions) , when I click uninstall button, the device is rebooted automatically.

Then I tried another app to change system font. When I click change font button ,again device is rebooted .

Simply said, No root required apps are working. Please guide me!!!

Model : swipe elite sense (marshmallow 6.0.1)

Comment: Is that SU you flashed *systemless?*. If that is the case it won't allow you to make modifications to system (which you are attempting to do) unless you make it System root . See [this for how](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/171563/131553). Take a complete Nandroid backup before you do this as a precaution. This explains possibly why you cannot uninstall. Double check in XDA forums for your device if you have flashed the correct version of TWRP