# Problem with installing a system app on rooted device

Tags: system-apps

I rooted my device to install an app as a system app. However after the installation of the app, I see the following error in the log cat

```
2019-03-14 18:19:19.319 4197-4197/? E/zygote64: Dex checksum does not match for dex: /system/priv-app/bmw.apk.Expected: 3853989528, actual: 1306952148
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix this?

Comment: If you have Magisk, you can avoid all of this hassle by using the Magisk module systemize. See my answer for more details. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208090/96277

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain, what does this error actually mean?