# How to install Split APK as system app?

Tags: apk, system-apps, supersu, lucky-patcher

I have copied it's APK to /system/app, but it crashes after a restart and also tried using Lucky patcher to move to system, but failed.

Android 7.0
Rooted with SuperSU.

Comment: Why do you want to use a split apk?

Comment: Some apps in playstore are split

Comment: Magisk provides a way for this systemlessly. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208090/96277. I however do not think split apk would work.

Comment: It won't work with systemizer